# Spring Data JPA Specification for a ManyToMany Unidirectional Relationship

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a setup where cats can be owned by many owners, and each owner can own several cats. Given this, I would like to write a specification to help me find all cats with a given owner name.

Here is a simple class setup.

```
@Entity
public class Cat extends AbstractEntity {
  @Column
  private String name;
}
```

* No getters/setters for conciseness. Id field is in the superclass.

```
@Entity
public class Owner extends AbstractEntity {
  @Column
  private String name;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name = "OWNER_2_CATS", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CAT_ID"))
  @OrderColumn(name = "order_column")
  private List<Cat> cats = Lists.newArrayList();
}
```

* No getters/setters for conciseness. Id field is in the superclass.

And here is a repository with a query that does work and a spec that does not work.

```
public interface CatRepository extends AtomicsRepository<Cat, Long> {

  // This query works.
  @Query("SELECT c FROM Owner o INNER JOIN o.cats c WHERE o.name = ?")
  List<Cat> findAllByOwner(String ownerName);

  // But how do I accomplish this in a specification?
  public static class Specs {
    static Specification<Cat> hasOwnerName(final String ownerName) {
      return (root, query, cb) -> {
        // These next lines don't work! What do I put here?
        Root<Owner> owner = query.from(Owner.class);
        owner.join("cats");
        return cb.equal(owner.get("name"), ownerName);
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me write the specification.

What I'm having trouble with is that this relationship seems to need to go against the grain of how the relationship is expressed: an owner has a `cats` list, but a cat does not have an `owners` list.

Comment: What do you even try to achieve?

Comment: `catRepository.findAll(CatRepository.Specs.hasOwnerName("Bob")` should return all cats that are owned by Bob.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Overview

The trickiness with this Spec is that you are querying the *Cat* with no direct relationship to *Owner*.

The general idea is to:

- Get a hold of the *Owner*.
- Relate the *Owner* with the *Cat* using *Owner.cats* relation membership.  We can do this using just the entities, and like JPA handle the entity @Id correlation for us.
- Mark the query on *Cat* as *distinct*.  Why? Because this is a @ManyToMany relationship and there may be multiple matching *Owner* for any given *Cat* depending on the *Owner* criteria used.

### Approach 1 - subquery

My preferred approach would be to use a subquery to introduce the *Owner*:

```
// Subquery using Cat membership in the Owner.cats relation
public static class Specs {
    static Specification<Cat> hasOwnerName(final String ownerName) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            query.distinct(true);
            Root<Cat> cat = root;
            Subquery<Owner> ownerSubQuery = query.subquery(Owner.class);
            Root<Owner> owner = ownerSubQuery.from(Owner.class);
            Expression<Collection<Cat>> ownerCats = owner.get("cats");
            ownerSubQuery.select(owner);
            ownerSubQuery.where(cb.equal(owner.get("name"), ownerName), cb.isMember(cat, ownerCats));
            return cb.exists(ownerSubQuery);
        };
    }
}
```

Which Hibernate 4.3.x generates SQL query like:

```
select cat0_.id as id1_1_
from cat cat0_
where 
    exists (
        select owner1_.id from owner owner1_ where
            owner1_.name=?
            and (cat0_.id in (
                select cats2_.cat_id from owner_2_cats cats2_ where owner1_.id=cats2_.owner_id
            ))
    )
```

### Approach 2 - cartesian product

An alternative is to use a cartesian product to introduce the *Owner*:

```
// Cat membership in the Owner.cats relation using cartesian product
public static class Specs {
    static Specification<Cat> hasOwnerName(final String ownerName) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            query.distinct(true);
            Root<Cat> cat = root;
            Root<Owner> owner = query.from(Owner.class);
            Expression<Collection<Cat>> ownerCats = owner.get("cats");
            return cb.and(cb.equal(owner.get("name"), ownerName), cb.isMember(cat, ownerCats));
        };
    }
}
```

Which Hibernate 4.3.x generates SQL query like:

```
select cat0_.id as id1_1_
from cat cat0_
cross join owner owner1_
where
    owner1_.name=?
    and (cat0_.id in (
        select cats2_.cat_id from owner_2_cats cats2_ where owner1_.id=cats2_.owner_id
    ))
```

Comment: What about if you have pagination? how to implement this functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a IN predicate getting the cat's id values with a sub-query.

```
public static class Specs {
  static Specification<Cat> hasOwnerName(final String ownerName) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
      //EntityType<Cat> Cat_ = root.getModel();
      final Subquery<Long> queryOwner = query.subquery(Long.class);// Check type of the Cat's ID attribute
      final Root<Owner> aliasOwner = queryOwner.from(Owner.class);
      //EntityType<Owner> Owner_ = aliasOwner.getModel();
      //final Join<Owner, Cat> aliasCatsOwner = aliasOwner.join(Owner_.cats);
      final Join<Owner, Cat> aliasCatsOwner = aliasOwner.join("cats");
      //queryOwner.select(aliasCatsOwner.<Long> get(Cat_.id)));
      queryOwner.select(aliasCatsOwner.<Long> get("id")));// Check type and name of the Cat's ID attribute
      queryOwner.where(cb.equal(Owner.<String> get("name"), ownerName));
      //return cb.in(root.get(Cat_.id).value(queryOwner);
      return cb.in(root.get("id").value(queryOwner);//check the name of ID attribute!
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is in this way:

```
 Page<Cat> findByOwner_Name(String ownerName, Pageable p);
```

But the difficulty is how to query those cats NOT owned by anyone, which equals

```
select * from cat where cat.id NOT IN (select cat.id from owner_has_cat);
```

Does anyone have idea please?