# Spring-data: Specifications & JPA criterias: how to left join and search/filter in collection properties

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

i just started to work with `Specification`'s and `Criteria`* objects and im stuck on doing a simple left join and compare a value with one of the joined entity properties.
As this find/select function im going to build will be sooner or later very dynamic i decided to work with with the Criteria objects instead of building different functions with different parameters.
My real entities has some more properties but i broke it down here to simplify it.

Before i was trying to do my first steps the `Specifification` i had a Repository function which was annotated with `@Query` and was working fine:

```
@Query( "SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Competition c " +
    "LEFT JOIN c.aliases a " +
    "WHERE " +
    "(lower(a.value) = :name OR lower(c.name) = :lowerCaseName) " +
    "... and so on ")
```

Later then i tried to build a Specification ignoring the lower case and `Competition` name and im still failing on how to do this join correct for comparing the name parameter with the `Alias` value property...

First entity:

```
@Entity
public class Competition extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)  
    @JoinTable(name="competition_name_alias", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="competition_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="alias_id"))  
    private Set<Alias> aliases = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}
```

Second entity:

```
@Entity
public class Alias extends AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String value;

    ...
}
```

Specification:

```
public static Specification<Competition> withLowerCaseName(String name) {
    return new Specification<Competition>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Competition> product, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
            final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

            Root<Competition> root = query.from(Competition.class);

            Subquery<Alias> subquery = query.subquery(Alias.class);
            SetJoin<Competition, Alias> aliases = root.join(Competition_.aliases);

            Predicate predicate = builder.equal(aliases.get(Alias_.value), name);
            builder.and(predicate);

            Predicate[] predicatesArray = new Predicate[predicates.size()];

            query.distinct(true);

            return builder.and(predicates.toArray(predicatesArray));
        }
    };
}
```

Using this function gets me all competitions and seems to ignore the name parameter. 
Switching on the hibernate debug/trace logging shows the reason. The generated sql has as the only where condition 
`where 1=1`.

There is also no name value shown while switching on the logging for the `descriptor.sql.BasicBinder` parameters...

Does anybody have a hint what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a slighly different example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841471/spring-data-jpa-specification-for-a-manytomany-unidirectional-relationship) and changed it for my constellation. Seems to work...

```
final Subquery<Alias> aliasSubquery = query.subquery(Alias.class);
final Root<Alias> alias = aliasSubquery.from(Alias.class);
final Expression<Set<Alias>> aliases = product.get(Competition_.aliases);
aliasSubquery.select(alias);
aliasSubquery.where(builder.equal(builder.lower(alias.get(Alias.value)), lowerCaseName), builder.isMember(alias, aliases));

builder.and(builder.exists(aliasSubquery));
```